# Встретил в коде конструкцию типа (смотрите внутри)

Tags: php

Встретил в коде конструкцию типа

```
$var <> ""
```

Это аналог

```
$var != ""
```

или нет?
Так вообще можно писать или считается плохим тоном?

Comment: В истории правок этого вопроса можно наблюдать войну двух человек с местным парсером.  
Машина победила :)

Answer (score 1):

http://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.operators.comparison.php

Comment: Сайт сейчас не работает, но спасибо за наводку. Нашел здесь http://www.puzzleweb.ru/php/14_compare.php . Пишут, что операторы идентичны.

Comment: Ни разу не видел, чтобы php.net не работал. Наверное это что-то с чакрами.